# Can we protect PRESENT from the Statistical Saturation Attack if we change the permutation layer to a random permutation layer?

Tags: attack, pseudo-random-permutation, present

This is continuation-question based on: [If PRESENT had different permutations s would that protect it against Statistical Saturation Attack?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51721/if-present-had-different-permutations-s-would-that-protect-it-against-statistica)
Can we protect PRESENT from Statistical Saturation Attacks by using:

1. unique perms for each round or just some rounds? (In this case, how many might *some* have to be?)
2. random, key-dependent (say), perms for some or all rounds?

Moreover, if these ideas can indeed protect PRESENT against SS attacks:

3. Could we use fewer than 31 rounds without causing vulnerabilities to other attacks?

See also
[What affect does the permutation layer have on the avalanche effect?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51655/what-affect-does-the-permutation-layer-have-on-the-avalanche-effect)